# Is it possible to use AWS Fsx Storage(windows file server) in Docker Windows Container

Tags: docker, amazon-fsx

In my local machine, I'm trying to build a container from windows docker image of MVC Core 6 web app, which uses files from AWS Fsx Storage.

In docker run, the application fails to start:

```
[15:29:46 ERR] Error occured while starting the application
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: \\amznfsxxxx\files
```

But I'm able to access the FSx storage from my local machine.

Any suggestions on how to make the Fsx storage accessible to the docker container?